# Finding a number sequence in this

Tags: java, design-patterns, numbers, sequence

I would just like to know if theres a way to find a number pattern because currently I'm using this.

```
    private int getRakeConfigForPatch(int patchId) {
    switch (patchId) {
    case 8550:
        return 708;
    case 8551:
        return 709;
    case 8552:
        return 710;
    case 8553:
        return 711;
    case 8554:
        return 712;
    case 8555:
        return 713;
    case 8556:
        return 714;
    case 8557:
        return 715;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I'd like to know how i can figure out the pattern for this sequence, because i have at least a hundred more cases to add in the same pattern and i don't really want an extra 200 lines of code if i don't need it.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like you can do this:

```
private int getRakeConfigForPatch(int patchId) {
    if (patchId >= 8550 && patchId <= 8557) {
        return patchId - 8550 + 708; // or patchId - 7842 for short, but less clear
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Of course, if you have a larger range, you'll need to change the `if` test, and if you have gaps in the progression, you could have several tests.

Comment: Oh my god, you just saved me a whole lot of time, Thanks :)

Comment: @TheLostMind I am, gotta wait 6 minutes though according to the site.

Comment: for love of Moses, can anyone explain this  return patchId - 8550 + 708; to me? how ted got this?

Comment: @TedHopp can you explain your answer better plz?

Comment: @TheLostMind Done, thanks for the info. I'll be sure to use it next time.

Comment: @KickButtowski - Look at the cases. When `patchId` is 8550, OP wants to return 708. When it is 8551, return 709, etc. Each time `patchId` goes up by 1, so does the return value. So first subtract 8550 so that when `patchId - 8550` is 0, return 708, etc. Then add 708 to simply return `patchId - 8550 + 708` with no further modification. At that point, lookup is unnecessary, so just get rid of the `switch` statement and use a `return` directly. (BTW, writing this explanation took about 10 times longer than the thought process itself.)

Answer (score 3):

```
private int getRakeConfigForPatch(int patchId) {

  return patchId - 7842;
 }
```